# How can I assign a name to the 'intersection' of index and columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pivot-table, rename

If I create a dataframe and than generate a pivot table from it, it keeps appearing a string in the upper left "cell" of the resulting table, like below. In this example it appears the string "n":

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
               'col2':['str_a1','str_a2','str_b1','str_b2','str_c1','str_c2']})
df2 = df.assign(n=df.groupby('col1').cumcount()).pivot(index='col1',columns='n',values='col2').reset_index()
df2

n col1       0       1
0    a  str_a1  str_a2
1    b  str_b1  str_b2
2    c  str_c1  str_c2
```

If I create the dataframe directly like below, it appears nothing. How can I include the "n" in this second option and how can I remove the "n" from the option above?

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c'],
                '0':['str_a1','str_b1','str_c1'],
                '1':['srt_a2','str_b2','str_c2']})
df3

  col1       0       1
0    a  str_a1  srt_a2
1    b  str_b1  str_b2
2    c  str_c1  str_c2
```

Comment: `df3.index.name='n'`

Comment: It´s not quite the same. When you create a pivot table and than reset its index, there´s a string that appears in the top left "cell" of it (one that is usually empty in a data frame). How can this value be accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by 'looking' at the dataframe 'horizontally' instead of 'vertically'. The 'n' that I was mentioning above was not the index name as splash58 pointed out. I must say that I used to think this way.

Than I noticed that the 'n' was in the same line as the other columns names's. Therefore it must be the name of the columns index.

In fact, if you do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
               'col2':['str_a1','str_a2','str_b1','str_b2','str_c1','str_c2']})
df2 = df.assign(n=df.groupby('col1').cumcount()).pivot(index='col1',columns='n',values='col2').reset_index()
print(df2)
```

you get:

```
n col1       0       1
0    a  str_a1  str_a2
1    b  str_b1  str_b2
2    c  str_c1  str_c2
```

After this, if you do:

```
df2.columns.name
```

you get:

```
'n'
```